# Can't see apps from existing Django project on Wagtail CMS

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm trying to integrate my Django project with Wagtail CMS. As it is done with existing Django project, I'm trying to follow [this documentation](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.1.1/getting_started/integrating_into_django.html).

After having done that, I can see my users on Wagtail, but not my apps. Should I need additional steps to bring my existing Django apps to Wagtail?

What I'm guessing is if the below two code snippets don't matter with it's added position. The documentation says to add them without specifying where exactly before or after.

**For INSTALLED_APPS**

```
'wagtail.contrib.forms',
'wagtail.contrib.redirects',
'wagtail.embeds',
'wagtail.sites',
'wagtail.users',
'wagtail.snippets',
'wagtail.documents',
'wagtail.images',
'wagtail.search',
'wagtail.admin',
'wagtail.core',

'modelcluster',
'taggit',
```

**For MIDDLEWAR**

```
'wagtail.core.middleware.SiteMiddleware',
'wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware',
```

Comment: I think you'll also need to register your models with the admin site. https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.4/reference/contrib/modeladmin/

Comment: That worked well. Thanks!

Comment: Please consider adding an answer to your question so that it may help somebody else out.

Comment: @xyres If you add your answer by yourself, I wanna choose yours as an answer for this question so that you can get the reward :) or Is it possible for me to move your comment to an answer?

Comment: Ah, thanks for the incentive. But I don't have any experience with wagtail cms. I don't want to post a link-only answer without some sample code and explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **`xyres`** explained in the comments, I tried following docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.4/reference/contrib/modeladmin.
As the documentation explain that, what I did is the following:

Add `wagtail.contrib.modeladmin` in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...
   'wagtail.contrib.modeladmin',
]
```

Then, I made a file named `wagtail_hooks.py` under Django app that I want to be seen in Wagtail CMS and put the below codes in the file.

**wagtail_hooks.py**

```
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.options import (
    ModelAdmin, modeladmin_register)
from .models import Book


class BookAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = Book
    menu_label = 'Book'  # ditch this to use verbose_name_plural from model
    menu_icon = 'pilcrow'  # change as required
    menu_order = 200  # will put in 3rd place (000 being 1st, 100 2nd)
    add_to_settings_menu = False  # or True to add your model to the Settings sub-menu
    exclude_from_explorer = False # or True to exclude pages of this type from Wagtail's explorer view
    list_display = ('title', 'author')
    list_filter = ('author',)
    search_fields = ('title', 'author')

# Now you just need to register your customised ModelAdmin class with Wagtail
modeladmin_register(BookAdmin)
```

With the above done, you will see your App model in Wagtail CMS.